# Image manipulation using Adobe Premiere

Tags: adobe-premiere

Does anyone know if there's relatively an easy way to create an effect in Adobe Premiere similar to the firefox addon Cooliris?  I.e. where you have a wall of thumbnails that can zoom off into the distance type thing?

If not does anyone know what I should look for to learn how to create it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be perfectly honest, I don't think Adobe Premiere is best suited for this effect. You most likely want to implement this using After Effects. 
You COULD manage to do it in Premiere but most likely you would need to individually keyframe the motion attributes for each clip. Keeping them all moving in the correct alignment would  be annoying.
It would be way easier in After Effects or any compositing package to lay out your clips how you want them, and then transform them as a group towards and away from your camera.

Comment: great thanks for this, After Effects does seem to be the right tool as it comes up a lot when I'm searching around for ideas...  Any ideas how I can achieve this being totally new to films?  Would I just load a bunch of thumbnails onto a black background and go from there?  many thanks